# Converting Date time to UTC Date and NULL Check in SQL

Tags: sql-server, utc

I have a requirement to convert the date to UTC and need to check is null or not in SQL.
and my final output I need to show like this below format

```
03/29/2016 10:02:38.550
```

My Code

```
SELECT ISNULL(
           CASE 
                WHEN CONVERT(DATE, NULL) = '1900-01-01' THEN ''
                ELSE CONVERT(
                         VARCHAR(24),
                         (
                             DATEADD(
                                 second,
                                 DATEDIFF(second, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()),
                                 GETDATE()
                             )
                         ),
                         101
                     ) + SPACE(1) + CONVERT(
                         VARCHAR(24),
                         (
                             DATEADD(
                                 second,
                                 DATEDIFF(second, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()),
                                 GETDATE()
                             )
                         ),
                         114
                     )
           END AS [DATE]
```

it's not working for me. can any one help me.

Thanks in advance

Updated ... its working fine Now

Comment: Define "not working", does it show an error, return unexpected results or what?

Comment: SQL Server already has the [SWITCHOFFSET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677244.aspx) and [TODATETIMEOFFSET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630335.aspx) functions to change offsets. `CONVERT` has nothing to do with offsets so I wouldn't expect the original code to have any effect

Comment: From @TheGeorgeL: Can we mark this as closed and can op put the answer they found?

Comment: BTW dates do *not* have any format. Format applies only when converting them to text, something that is typically best left to the client.